# After data recovery software needed

Tags: photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

I accidentally deleted all files from one of my hard drives. I have recovered most of the files, but there is around 1 TB of data. I mainly want to recover my pictures, but they are mixed with thousands of other random/damaged files/photos.

Is there software which can scan all "good" photos and make a new folder containing them? Or a script that I can run to do this?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Open to any OS? If so, a script can be built pretty easily using `find . -name *.jpg` then piped through imagemagick's "identify" command. If you're open to Linux/Unix tools I'll find my old script to filter out bad images.

Answer (score 1):

Found my old script that incorporated a function like what you're looking for. This is using Bash and Imagemagick (on Linux):

```
#!/bin/env bash
 for img in `find /loc/of/saved/items -type f -iname "*.jpg"`; do
    if identify "${img}" &> /dev/null; then
        mv ${img} /identified/files
    fi
done
```

Comment: Pet peave  replace `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/env bash`. Does the same **if** there is a bash in /usr/bin, but also works if it is elsewhere (e.g. when the bash in /usr/local/bin/ and the default is sh, dash or just about anything)

Comment: Learn something new everyday, thanks! I was wondering why I had seen that with `python`.

Comment: If replaces the maintenance of scripts with dozens of interpreters with the maintenance of a single program. Quite nice if you need to take care of more than a few systems with different operating systems. (and thus the interpreters in various places).